# Carbon copy cloner to image OS X lion and restore from disk image

Tags: backup, disk-utility, data-recovery, carbon-copy-cloner

Is it possible to create an image of my 64gb 2012 Macbook Air using Carbon Copy Cloner so that I can recover from that image (if my Mac does not boot) even if I am not connected to the internet?

Answer (score -2):

The [getting started](http://help.bombich.com/kb/overview) section of the CCC online documentation will get you on your way.

For Carbon Copy Cloner support, please post questions to the [Bombich Software Help Desk](http://help.bombich.com)

Comment: The answer should be self contained here and only use links to gove more information.